# issue sending a retrieving value using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a cleaner code of my preview problem, the idea is to send and retrieve a value using ajax, but the value is not being sent nor ajax seems to work. I updated this code because this way it could be easily tested on any machine. First time using ajax. Here is the code:

Javascript

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#centro').click( function() {
$.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
        alert(output_string);
                $('#cuentas').html(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call    

  });

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <?php
  $result = 'works';
  ?>

  <form id="form">
  <div id="centro">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
  </form>

  <div id="cuentas">
  </div>
```

PHP file, request.php

```
 <?php
 $centro = $_POST['centro'];
 $output_string = ''.$centro;
 echo json_encode($output_string);
 ?>
```

Comment: You are spitting out **JSON** data on **request.php** but not treating your AJAX response as **JSON**.

Comment: how can I treat ajax responde as JSON? @pmandell first time using ajax or json.

Comment: You have a extra `}` at the 2nd last line, try to remove it...

Comment: yea @PalashMondal, I did remove it but still it doesn't work

Comment: Does the click-event for #centro execute at all?

Comment: no, it doesn't @bestprogrammerintheworld

Comment: Ok. How is jQuery library included?

Comment: your `json`  would also not be a valid `json string`.

Comment: I don't see any end-tag for <div id="centro"> ? (maybe you have chosen not to show end-tag for that div. But if end-tag is not there, jQuery would not find it). Try to put the form id="form" inside of that div as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, now this works, plus I added a gif loader:

Javascript:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#centro').click( function() {
 var result = $("input#centro").val(); 
 $.ajax({
    url: 'request.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: { 'dataString': result },
    beforeSend: function(){
                   $("#loader").show();
               },
    success: function(output_string){
     $("#loader").hide();
           $('#cuentas').html(output_string);  
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call    

  });

 });
 </script>
```

HTML

```
 <?php
 $result = 'works';
 ?>

 <form id="form">
 <div id="centro">
 <div id="loader" style="display:none"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" width="20px" height="20px"></div>
 <a href="#">Click here</a> 
 <br>
 <input type="hidden" name="centro" id="centro" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
 </form>
<div id="cuentas">
</div>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 $data = $_POST['dataString'];
 $output_string = '';
 $output_string = '<h3>'.$data.' '.'testing'.'</h3>';
 echo $output_string;
 ?>
```

Output: "works testing"

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing Your Code A bit like Below .

**Jquery part**

```
success: function(d){
         var output=d[0].data; // Will output only first record  
          $('#cuentas').html(output);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
```

**PHP PART**

```
$centro = $_POST['centro'];
$output_string = array('data'=>$centro);
echo json_encode($output_string);
```

if still not works Check The `Developer tool` in chrome or `firebug` in firefox to monitor the Requests

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
  <?php
  $result = 'works';
  ?>

  <form id="form">
  <div id="centro">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
  </form>

  <div id="cuentas">
  </div>
```

I miss an ending-tag for the div id="centro". Therefore the click-event for jQuery("#centro") will not trigger.

I suppose it should be like this: (Always set `<form>` and `</form>` inside OR outside of a div, do not mix and put `<form>` outside and `</form>` inside of a div. Some things wont work as expected when you do a mix like that.

```
  <?php
  $result = 'works';
  ?>

  <div id="centro">
  <form id="form">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
  </form>
  </div> ><!-- end of div centro -->

  <div id="cuentas">
  </div>
```